# Dax cache performance issue when bombard with multiple requests

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, es6-promise, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am working on a an api which will get lot of hits so that, I cached it. Each call will have a set of ids which needs to be passed in the request itself  and I cant use batch to get the items due to design issues. So I am calling get operation multiple times for all of the eventIds

```
async function getSummaryFromDax(id) {
        const perf = perfMeasure({enable: true});
        let params = {
            TableName: Table,
            Key: {
                id
            }
        };
        //todo dax not working as expected.
        perf("parallel");
        const result = await daxCacheClient.get(params).promise();
        perf("parallel");

        return {result: result.Item,perf: perf._summary};
    }
```

This function mocks the functionality. I just hard coded the id.

```
const {queryStringParameters= {}} = event;
    const {calls = 1, id = "CwjPJ4rcdIOOi3yFhpHhDiHzHKo-w8aRaVAYR"} = queryStringParameters;
    dummy.length = calls;
    dummy.fill(id);
    const proms = dummy.map(async id=>{
        return getSummaryFromDax(id)
    })


    const response = await Promise.all(proms);
    perf("handler");
```

If the **calls =1** , means, 1 db get  call will be done. The time taken to get the db response is **2ms**. When I increase the calls count say, **100**, I am getting average performance of **200 ms** per **each get operation.** Why does that happening ?.

Comment: How are you writing the items?